# Grails 3.0.3, Error running intrgration test using test-app

Tags: grails, testing, integration

I am using Grails 3.0.3, and added an integration test using create-integration-test and getting this error with both application.yml and application.groovy.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can you please help? Basically I want to know how to do integration test with Grails 3.0.3?

Comment: Did you try `gradlew integrationTest`?

Comment: More details will be required to look into this issue. Can you add the test and some more details about the class?

Comment: dmahapatro: I am having the same prblem with 3.0.9 and using `./gradlew integrationTest` did not work (I got the same stack trace). This isn't my question so I can't edit it but if you're on the Grails Slack I can dm you there